# Placing letters under underlined text in XSL-FO using Apache FOP

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have a project that requires me to place a ID string under some underlined text in a passage of text.

Here is an example using an inline SVG object with a gray border to show the layout:

[image: sample use of SVG inline to simulate inline]

I can get close using an inline element with a baseline-shift and then use SVG to render the text. However this has the disadvantage (I think) that I have to manually put in the width of the SVG in pixels, which seems very complicated for such a simple layout.

Here is the XSL-FO markup for this:

```
<fo:block>
Normal text
<fo:inline baseline-shift="-100%">
    <fo:instream-foreign-object text-align="center" display-align="center" border="solid silver 1px">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="25" width="120" viewport="0 0 120 25">
            <text x="60" y="10" fill="black" text-anchor="middle" text-decoration="underline" font-size="12pt">underlined text with id</text>
            <text x="60" y="25" fill="black" text-anchor="middle" font-size="12pt">123</text>
        </svg>
    </fo:instream-foreign-object>
</fo:inline>
normal text.
</fo:block>
```

So my question is: Can I perform this layout in Apache FOP XSL-FO without using instream-foreign-object and SVG?  If I can not, is there some way to not have to put the width in the SVG in pixels?  Or is there some way to calculate how many pixels the SVG will take to render?

I should also note inline-container is not supported in Apache FOP.

https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/compliance.html

Thanks in advance! - Dan

Comment: There is not enough information in your question to provide an answer. Example: What happens if the text you are placing this within warps to multiple lines? What happens to the following lines of text ... specifically with the line spacing and the fact that what you are drawing impinges on it? You have not fully thought through this or if you have, you have certainly not given enough information for someone to even recommend solutions.

Comment: I have no experience with what is supported by Apache FOP, but if I was using RenderX I would (1) format the fragments you request to the area tree format (called XEPOUT). From that, you can determine the fragment width and height. Then (2) would either (a) use that fragment as an image (that is supported in RenderX XEP) or (b) you could convert that area tree to SVG and you would know that pixel width you need. We do this is projects to apply SVG gradients to multi-line text that is formatted in the document.

Comment: Hi Kevin, to answer your question the underlined text should work exactly like any other underlined text.  It should wrap if it needs to.  As I stated in my question, my goal is to do this layout with Apache FOP and without using SVG and without having to manually estimate the width of the text within the SVG. Thanks - Dan

Comment: Could you use MathML?

Comment: Just to clarify then using the example above, let's say the calculated line break occurs at the word "text" ... what does this look like? The words "underlined text" on one line, the words "with id" on the next line and where does the bottom part go? And what does the line spacing look like in all cases since the object you are drawing is larger than the height of a single line? Is the whole paragraph line spacing set to the highest height of this fragment or? Until all the requirements of the possible occurrences are understood, it is not possible to exactly answer.

Comment: > where does the bottom part go?
in the center of the underlined text

>And what does the line spacing look like in all cases since the object you are drawing is larger than the height of a single line?
The line-height would need to be adjusted to avoid overlaps

> Is the whole paragraph line spacing set to the highest height of this fragment or?
No.  Just the line that needs it.

> Until all the requirements of the possible occurrences are understood, it is not possible to exactly answer.
I was not looking for an exact answer.  Just trying to see if anyone had done this in Apache FOP.

Comment: Kevin Said: "until all the requirements of the possible occurrences are understood, it is not possible to exactly answer."

Dan's Response:  Actually, I was not looking for an *exact* answer.  I was only trying to see if anyone had done anything like this in Apache FOP without using SVG and what fo elements they used. Thanks!

Comment: That is not possible. "Centered" has no concept under two separate fragments that would exist on two different lines. First, it would only be possible using the "concepts" of an image. And since your width is variable, it is only possible through composing this fragment separately in a first pass. You can execute the engine and format only the underlined text with marker below and then use that "like an image" within another formatting run to include that into the text. This is the most likely solution (and by the way, that is how any formatting engine would do it).

Comment: And one more note, setting line-height in FOP does not work, it is not supported so you would not be able to set the height to compensate for the enlarged area. Doing this with RenderX, it would be possible and a somewhat trivial exercise as long as the "chunk" is to remain together in on line, doing it as described with FOP I do not believe is possible because of the line height requirements.

Comment: @KevinBrown is correct, you more than likely have to compose this thing twice: once to create a true and accurate result of the multi-line graphic you need, and then the 2nd time using these items as assets in your final print (referencing them from your FO).  These are techniques we do quite frequently and have solved *MANY* things you can't do with FOP or FO for that matter using RenderX intermediate format.  Once you have a custom reader/writer at your disposal and a means to POST-Inject your assets back into your FO (or XSLT template) these procedures become quite routine.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample done as I suggested with RenderX using the formatting tree. [image: Sample Output]

Format the desired fragments to the intermediate format ... something like this for a single one:

```
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master margin="0mm" master-name="MASTERsite1" page-width="214mm" page-height="29pt">
                <fo:region-body margin="0mm"/>
            </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>    
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="MASTERsite1">
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                <fo:table>
                    <fo:table-body>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell><fo:block text-decoration="underline" text-align="center">This is Underlined Text with ID</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell><fo:block text-align="center">1234567</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                    </fo:table-body>  
                </fo:table>
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence> 
    </fo:root>
```

The output of that would be this:

```
    <xep:document xmlns:xep="http://www.renderx.com/XEP/xep" producer="XEP 4.19 build 20110414" creator="Unknown" author="Unknown" title="Untitled">
        <xep:page width="162708" height="29000" page-number="1" page-id="1">
    <xep:word-spacing value="0"/>
    <xep:letter-spacing value="0"/>
    <xep:font-stretch value="1.0"/>
    <xep:font family="Helvetica" weight="400" style="normal" variant="normal" size="12000"/>
    <xep:gray-color gray="0.0"/>
    <xep:text value="This is Underlined Text with ID" x="0" y="18734" width="162708"/>
    <xep:line x-from="0" x-till="162708" y-from="17534" y-till="17534" thickness="600" style="solid"/>
    <xep:text value="1234567" x="58002" y="4334" width="46704"/>
    </xep:page>
    </xep:document>
```

Where you would modify the result to change the page width, but it's right in the text as the width of the text element of concern, that is change:

```
 <xep:page width="606614" height="29000" page-number="1" page-id="1">
```

so the width is from the text line of concern, programmatically pick up the x-till from xep:line or the xep:text line (changing as above). Note, this is exactly equivalent to your SVG example except you have the number programmatically to access right inside this file.

last, using this "file" as an image, one would then use:

```
 <fo:external-graphic src="test19.xep" content-type="application/xepout" alignment-baseline="central"/>
```

Now, while you say look at all those steps, this is a solution and all of the above could be automated into a single process chain. First loop through and format all of the objects of concern and make little files from them, then a second pass would instead of formatting those fragments, would use them as images.

Note: The line spacing shown in the attached image of the result cannot be done with FOP (I believe), I think that is a limitation of FOP.

Note #2: I am not a FOP expert and I know nothing of it's implementation, specifically using the area tree as an image in a document. If FOP is a must, I would suggest looking into it. You could just as easily convert the area tree to SVGs and use them as you would be able to use all their dimensions or better just read the area tree into the second transform and generate instream-foreign-object SVGs from it right inline.

Comment: i tested with FOP and you can do this similarly.

Comment: Wow, you guys are awesome!  Very impressive.  I will look into RenderX and see if I can download a trial version.

Thanks again for your help!