# XSL-FO mad libs layout

Tags: layout, vertical-alignment, xsl-fo

Trying to create a layout for a mad libs page.

Example:

I **_______** all the way from **_______** to

```
(verb)             (place)
```

(The "(verb) and "(place)" hints should be right under the lines, and no background color)

```
<fo:block font-size="20pt" font-family="serif">
     I ___________ all the way from ___________ to
</fo:block>
```

How to get the hints down there?

Had no success so far, any ideas how to do it? (if possible at all)

Using Apache FOP.

Comment: Can you show an example of your XSLT code?

Comment: Have no XSLT code, just writing FO tags directly.

Comment: Ok, then you may get more help if you post your code FO in this case.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22253279/placing-letters-under-underlined-text-in-xsl-fo-using-apache-fop/22393638#22393638 for a similar question. Depending on what *all* the requirements are. You could also develop a custom font with an overbar over every character and use a shift to shift them down.

Comment: NOTE: Since you seem to have a fixed width for your "area", you could solve your problem with the SVG method the person was attempting in that referenced question. He could not use it because his area to be put inline varied in width. If your "________" are the same length, you could use that. And if your combinations are canned (meaning, they are always either "verb" or "place" or ... you could just create a set of SVGs for each and use one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are generating the FO and have control, this (should) work for you.

```
        <fo:table>
            <fo:table-body>
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell><fo:block>I</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell><fo:block>&#160;<fo:leader leader-length="1in" leader-pattern="rule"/>&#160;</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell><fo:block>all the way from</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell><fo:block>&#160;<fo:leader leader-length="1in" leader-pattern="rule"/>&#160;</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell><fo:block>to</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell><fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell><fo:block text-align="center">(verb)</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell><fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell><fo:block text-align="center">(place)</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell><fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
            </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
```

Tested with RenderX, this renders perfectly as expected.

[image: RenderX Sample]

However, I tested also with Apache FOP and got unexpected results. You could/should report as a bug to Apache as their rendering is wrong. I am afraid you will need to use the SVG method listed in the comments above.

[image: Apache FOP sample]

Comment: Checked the link mentioned by @kevin-brown. Came up with this "solution".

    <fo:block font-size="20pt">
         I 
        <fo:inline font-size="16pt" baseline-shift="-16pt" text-decoration="overline">
       &#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;(verb)&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;   
        </fo:inline>
    all the way from
    </fo:block>    
    
  
  
Sorry, as you see I'm having big problems getting the formatting correct here.